# Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy cmdlet assigning policy as user instead of application

Tags: azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-automation

We’re seeing an issue when trying to add an access policy on a KeyVault for providing permissions to secrets on an automation account service principal. We’re using the below cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "KeyVaultName" -ApplicationId "0aaa8314-872d-41ef-a75e-d3a5ec5b31e6" -ObjectId "443d03a7-6b76-47d1-9406-8fb87c17bbc3" -PermissionsToSecrets recover,delete,backup,set,restore,list,get
```

when the cmdlet executes, we see something like this in the portal. Note the Icon which seems to look like a User.

[image]

Despite seeing this in the access policies, the automation account’s runbooks still fail with the error “Forbidden” when trying to access the keyvault:

```
Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret : Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'
At C:\Modules\User\CustomModule.psm1:28 char:22
+ ... clientID = (Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $global:ManagementKeyV ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret], KeyVaultErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.KeyVault.GetAzureKeyVaultSecret
```

Tried in multiple ways for providing access to keyvault for the automation account service principal using the below cmdlets but still getting the same result.

```
Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "KeyVaultName" -ObjectId "443d03a7-6b76-47d1-9406-8fb87c17bbc3" -PermissionsToSecrets recover,delete,backup,set,restore,list,get -BypassObjectIdValidation 

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName "KeyVaultName" -ServicePrincipalName ((Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId "0aaa8314-872d-41ef-a75e-d3a5ec5b31e6").ServicePrincipalNames[0]) -PermissionsToSecrets recover,delete,backup,set,restore,list,get
```

However, after manually adding the same service principal from the portal, we see a different icon for the same service principal.

[image]

Can someone please help out with this? Am I doing something wrong?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy [-VaultName]   -ServicePrincipalName "0aaa8314-872d-41ef-a75e-d3a5ec5b31e6"  -PermissionsToSecrets recover,delete,backup,set,restore,list,get

Where SPN is the Application Id.

I know it's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

For 2022, ran on Azure Cloud shell 2.43.0:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name myKeyVault --object-id <object-id> --secret-permissions <secret-permissions> --key-permissions <key-permissions> --certificate-permissions <certificate-permissions>
```

Remove the flags you don't want.

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/assign-access-policy?tabs=azure-cli